# Detect source of error "glibc detected memory corruption"

Tags: c++, linux, memory, malloc, glibc

After adding new function from project I get "glibc detected memory corruption"

Error doesn't specify line on which error occures.

How to detect the source of the error ?

**Update:**

Also worth to mention, I don't use malloc in my code explicitly and my code is C++.

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) is usually a good place to start.

Comment: You can use valgrind with tool memcheck to check your memory.

Comment: The line at which the error "occurs" would be nearly useless in determining the source (cause) of the error.  The new function you added is not very likely to include the cause of the error (unless you added it to a project that was previously VERY well tested).  This kind of error can hide for a long time (through execution time and/or versions of your code) and symptoms show up far removed from cause.  R_Kapp already gave the usual suggestion (Valgrind).  I'm just trying to help you understand why looking at the failure more directly won't help find the cause.

Comment: Another useful tool is the environment variable `MALLOC_CHECK_`, i.e. `MALLOC_CHECK_=2 ./yourprog`. Sometimes this finds memory errors earlier than normal execution and aborts the program (producing a core dump that you can then examine with a debugger).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `g++` or `clang` you should enable [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), it is good at detecting this kind of errors. Compile and link your code with `-fsanitize=address`.